# Как обновить текст тега?

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx

На javafx создал приложение, добавил браузер javafx.scene.web.WebView, загрузил html контент, в html контенте есть только один тег p

```html
<p id="p1">text</p>

<script>
var ppp = document.getElementById("p1");
function f1(t) {
  ppp.innerHTML = t;
}
</script>
```

Надо сделать так чтобы это тег

постоянно обновлялся. Извините не смог проще или красиво объяснить. Но по моему вы поняли. Надо постоянно обновить этот тег через Java

Comment: У вас в коде уже написана готовая функция, которая обновляет текст тега. Так что вопрос непонятен совершенно; также непонятно, при чём тут вообще Java

Comment: постоянно это как? ежесекундно?

Comment: Да ежесекундно надо обновить. Я обновляю вот так webView.getEngine().executeScript("f1(" + Math.random() + ")");

Comment: Можно конечно обновить многократно с помошью Platform.runLater() но это часто вызывает ошибку.

Comment: В javafx есть такие классы как Service и  Task может эти классы приходит в помошь. Но я не знаю как с их помошью можно часто обновить

Comment: По моему вопрос нормальный. Чтобы вы смогли ответить, вы должны хорошо знать JavaFx

Comment: @BahodirBahodir а что за информация там?

Comment: Информация может быть что угодно, я просто хотел научиться как это можно сделать

Comment: Если вы знаете в javaFx нельзя обновить контент через другой поток, а если обновить в потоке JavaFx то обновляется только один раз

Answer (score 1):

setInterval перезапускает функцию через каждый указанный промежуток в миллисекундах. Одна секунда = 1000; Если внутри параграфа всё равно не должно быть HTML, а только чистый текст - полезнее будет использовать `innerText` (чтобы избегать лишней проверки на наличие HTML, вдруг там километровый текст);

```js
const p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
setInterval(function () {
  p1.innerHTML = Math.random();
},1000);
```

```html
<p id="p1">text</p>
```

Comment: Правила, в html контент не надо внесить изменения, мне нужен java код

Comment: Потом я тоже очень хорошо разбираюсь в html и javascript. Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужен это реализовать на javafx